# Windows Update from Intranet URL using Powershell command

Tags: windows, update

We are using SCCM for updates and I am building the automation to build the server. the SCCM takes almost 15 minutes to connect to it even if it is configured so I need to use the Internal Update URL to do windows updates. Suppose I have the URL as http://xxx:8534 . How can I use Powershell Windows update to get the updates from URL instead of going out the server or over Internet.